# What is the best standard for shortening words in the code?

Tags: python, coding-style, standards

I hope this question does not get closed/downvoted, as it really takes a good portion of the time I spend coding.

As a developer more focused on Python, I try to follow PEP8 standard, but for some variable names it becomes really tricky to me.

Let's say the word TEMPERATURE.

If I want to have a variable to store a list of temperatures, I would name it:

```
temperature_list = []
```

However, as the code gets more complex, let's say I have to call a function with the temperature_list as an argument:

```
calling_function(variable_with_long_name, temperature_list, another_long_name_variable)
```

You can clearly see where it leads...

So I decide to rename `temperature_list` to `temp_list`. Which can sound as a good choice, right?

Except...

If I also want to store TEMPORARY FILES in a list, I may occur to have:

```
temp_list = []
temp_file_list = []
```

It may come to the point where my variables start messing around and turning the code a bit tricky to follow.

What is the convention and what other actions do programmers do when face such situation? Is there any reference to follow for such cases, like a casebook of good variable names for certain nouns?

-- edit

*If you vote for closing it, at least explain why! --'*

Comment: PEP 8 says "reflect usage rather than implementation", which indicates to me that most of the time you should not include the type name in your variable name. Pluralizing the name to simply `temperatures` should be sufficient to indicate to the reader "this is a non-scalar object that can be iterated over, and probably indexed", which is good enough for the common case. (Posting as a comment and not an answer since this is my own subjective interpretation)

Comment: The number of times this will happen in  your career -- needing words like both "TEMPERATURE" and "TEMPORARY" -- is going to be very small. In the real world long names just aren't much of an issue if you write sensible code.

Comment: @Kevin you should repost your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Kevin with regards to PEP8 I believe you are right, but I tend to declare the type I expect the variable to be, as it helps for clear unit tests. Still, that was a good insight of yours.

Comment: @BryanOakley, what should be the sensible code in this case? Even if small occurrences, I consider these as relevant cases when you are dealing with international teams composed by non-native english speakers.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira: in this specific case, I would use `temperature` and perhaps `temp` or `temp_files`.

Comment: If your concern is with making sure teams of international non-english-speakers can understand your code, you should probably mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you are required to find clever names, that are not too long, but explains the variable properly. When this fails, or there are too many variables doing similar work (so would have close names), you can choose to explain the variables in a docstring or a comment, and give short names (still meaningful names, not a, b, etc...)

```
def function(a, b):
    """
    l_variable used for bla bla,
    lo_variable is good for bla bla.
    """

    l_variable = 12
    lo_variable = 123
    lon_variable = 1234 # This is an integer bla bla
```

When you really have the need for long variable names, where I sometimes cannot avoid myself, I try to lower line lengths while not breaking the purpose of the code. For example breaking lines in function calls(like in your example).

```
def f(a, b, c):
    print a + b + c

this_is_a_long_variable_name = "Stack"
this_is_an_even_longer_variable_name = "Over"
this_is_the_longest_variable_name_in_this_example = "flow"

f(this_is_a_long_variable_name,
    this_is_an_even_longer_variable_name,
    this_is_the_longest_variable_name_in_this_example)
```